# Mysql query with multiple tables and foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, social-networking

Consider this mysql tables structure (useful to store `private/group` chat messages):

```
USERS
user_id
username
password

GROUPS (= DISCUSSIONS / TOPICS)
group_id
name

GROUPS_MEMBERS (= MEMBERS OF A SPECIFIC DISCUSSION / TOPIC)
group_id
user_id

MESSAGES
message_id
timestamp
from_user_id
destination_type (enum - group, user)
destination_id
```

Can you please help me with the query to retrieve the list of the 5 more recent dicussions (either private or group) in which a specific user has been a active?

**Important:**

I don't have actual code since I'm just deciding how to structure the database tables. The `table structure` presented above it's pretty self-explanatory (destination_id is a reference to `group_id`, and `group members` are all the `users` that will receive a message. Finally, all messages sent between the users of a specific group make a `discussion` or `topic`).

Here is what I want to do (it's very easy... don't over-think it... it's like any chat/messaging system like Facebook or Gmail etc).

When a user `logs in` and opens the chat he will of course see all the latest `discussion` which he is/has been a part of. In a chronological `DESC` order.

**So I need to write the query to retrieve the latest 5 GROUP_IDs (= discussions) in chronological DESC order. But only the discussions which the logged-in user is a part of.**(Of course I have the id of the logged-in user.. for example 16)

P.s. I didn't build this table structure myself but it seems logic; the only problem is the one presented above.

Comment: you should start writing some code so we can provide our advice

Comment: Show your code, what have you done so far? So that we can help you out.

Comment: Alternatively, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I'll do that right now... thank you for the advice

Comment: If by dicussions you mean messages, then the query you need to write is very simple. if you mean something other the messages, you need to refine your question.

Comment: Is everything clear now?

Comment: Anyway just think about Facebook... when you go to your private messages and you see the list of all your discussions with your friends (either one-on-one or group discussions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my suggestion. You can get different records by using `DISTINCT` and get only five records by using `LIMIT`. You can replace `logged_in_user_id` with the login id.

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUPS.group_id FROM USERS
  JOIN GROUP_MEMBERS ON USERS.user_id = GROUP_MEMBERS.user_id
  JOIN GROUPS ON GROUPS.group_id = GROUP_MEMBERS.group_id
  JOIN MESSAGES ON destination_type = 'group' AND destination_id = GROUPS.group_id
  WHERE USERS.user_id = logged_in_user_id
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC
  LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: I'll verify it as soon as possible but seems right. There is probably one type error: second line "GROUPS.user_id" instead of "GROUP_MEMBERS.user_id". Please correct it and I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Igor Carmagna:

I have gone through your question and according to that i think you are required list the top 5 messages which have been left by the end users right ?. So for that please please follow below given steps.

1) First and for most thing you are required to do is that Join.
2) In this step you are required to use max() function which will give you list of the users on the base of messages received. Now, according to your question you are required to have only top 5 records so you are bound use (max-5) function this will given top 5 records

Hope this will make you day !! 
Cheers :) :P

Comment: So you can try with the logic given above in my answer and if you wish to have only logged in users then you have to add one more condition for that nothing else. ....

Comment: Sorry can you write an example query?... I really don't understand how to implement what you suggested.  Don't mind the "logged-in" part. If you'd have to retrieve the latest 5 acitve discussions (=group_id) of the user with user_id = 16 ..... what would you do?

Comment: Hello 

I have created the a table in my local with 3 fields like Id, Name and Logged_id and below given is the query which i have tested with my phpmyadmin and it is working well now you are just required add the joins for getting the other required details of yours.

SELECT * FROM test_data WHERE id > (SELECT MAX(id) - 5 FROM test_data where logged_id=16)

Comment: I'm really thankful that you tried to help but I'm pretty positive that this is not what I'm asking. In the query you did not consider the timestamp of the messages in the "messages" table. That should be the first thing. Then the query should also filter the list of the recent messages, to obtain only the ones published by or sent to the user with id = 16

Comment: In other words I need to know the latest groups in which messages were published (among the groups/discussions the user is a part of)

Comment: If my answer has helped in you please have up word for my answer!!! Thanks in Advance :P :)